# texstudio command to jump to content

Tags: texstudio

I didn't save my texprofile before reinstallation.
I search the command to jump to the content...
for example

`\begin{exercice}
    contenu...
  \end{exercice}`

What is the default shortcut for mac ?

Sorry for the newbie question.

Thanks you

Comment: I don't follow, do you mean auto-completion of commands/environments? I'd guess that is the Tab-key.

Comment: yes for example my cursor is on \begin and I want to be on "contenu..." other example \dfrac{numerator}{denominator} but tab does not work on mac os x but I want to reaffect the command to another shortcut but not find in menu ...

Answer (score 1):

I found !

It was in the last menu editor !

The command that I want to map in shortcut was in: Preferences -
 - Shortcuts - Editor - Basic key mapping - Move cursor right (1
 characters) (in advanced mod)

Comment: the command that I want to map in shortcut was in : preferences - shortcuts - editor - basic key mapping - Move cursor right (1 characters) (in advanced mod)

Comment: You can edit your posts, so rather than adding important parts of the answer in comments, click the edit button below your answer and add it there.